# Dictionary in Go

Tags: python, dictionary, go, struct

I'm just starting out with Go, and coming from Python I'm trying to find the equivalent of a dict in Python. In Python I would do this:

```
d = {
    'name': 'Kramer',  # string
    'age': 25          # int
}
```

I first found the `map` type, but that only allows for one type of value (it can't handle both `ints` and `strings`. Do I really need to create a `struct` whenever I want to do something like this? Or is there a type I'm missing?

Comment: Check out Go's [maps](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

Comment: Also, do the tour https://tour.golang.org

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - but maps don't accept multiple value types (both strings and ints).

Comment: You can use `map[string]interface{}` so that they'll take anything.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use dicts and maps as Javascript-style objects. What you need is a struct, not a map.

Comment: I don't understand high negative vote count on this question, the OP basically answered the question themselves. Yes, `struct` is the way to go.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Basically the problem is that it's hard to encounter a requirement to store values of different types in the same map instance *in real code.*

In your particular case, you should just use a struct type, like this:

```
type person struct {
  name string
  age  int
}
```

Initializing them is no harder than maps thanks to so-called "literals":

```
joe := person{
  name: "Doe, John",
  age:  32,
}
```

Accessing individual fields is no harder than with a map:

```
joe["name"] // a map
```

versus

```
joe.name // a struct type
```

---

All in all, please consider reading an introductory book on Go
*along* with your attemps to solve problems with Go,
as you inevitably are trying to apply your working knowledge
of a dynamically-typed language to a strictly-typed one,
so you're basically trying to write Python in Go, and that's
counter-productive.

I'd recommend starting with
[The Go Programming Language](http://www.gopl.io).

There are also [free books on Go](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Books).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I just have to get used to defining every structure which I use, instead of creating them on the fly like in all the other languages which I'm used to (Python/php/js/Ruby). Thanks again for your sane answer, instead of all the rather annoyed messages I get on this question.. :-)

Answer (score 12):

That's probably not the best decision, but you can use `interface{}` to make your map accept any types:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    dict := map[interface{}]interface{} {
        1: "hello",
        "hey": 2,
    }
    fmt.Println(dict) // map[1:hello hey:2]
}
```

Comment: Why would this not be a good decision? If this works I would love the flexibility.

Comment: Well, if you really need flexibility, go for it!

Comment: So what if I would like to initiate an array of maps? Any idea how I would do that?

Comment: `arrayOfMaps := make([]map[interface{}]interface{}, 10)` will make an array with 10 elements. You really should take [golang's tour](https://tour.golang.org)

Comment: @kramer65 This is not a good idea because trying to use such a map requires enormous effort. Type assertions and type switches galore.

Comment: "Well, if you really need flexibility, go for it!" -> If you really need the flexibility, Go is not the right tool for the job. Try Python.

Comment: @RickyA when building restful web apps, we will need at least this much flexibility (eg: for JSON reponses).